# Get data & Ignore null value when using group by in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to group by the data based on `content_related_group`. But there's a condition where content_related_group is null, and I don't want it to group the data with null value.

I've tried like this:

```
$products = DB::table('product')
        ->select('*', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('content_related_group')  
        ->paginate(9);
```

It's working, but it grouping the null data into one. I don't want it, what I want is to get all data from database and only group the the data with same `content_related_group`into one.

Example data:

```
id   |   content_related_group
1    |   content_1
2    |   content_1
3    |   null
4    |   null
```

Result (the null data keep separated from each other & the same content_related_group is grouped:

```
id   |  content_related_group
1    | content_1
2    | null
3    | null
```

It is possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this if you want to remove the null rows:

```
$products = DB::table('product')
        ->select('*', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->whereNotNull('content_related_group')  
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('content_related_group')  
        ->paginate(9);
```

try this if you want to keep null value grouped to one row

```
$x_products   =   DB::table('product')->whereNull('content_related_group');

$products = DB::table('product')
        ->whereNotNull('content_related_group')
        ->union($x_products)
        ->select('*', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('content_related_group')  
        ->paginate(9);
```

Comment: Thanks, but It ignoring the null value by skipping data with null value, I want to keep get the data with null value & grouping the other's with same content_related_group

Comment: hm, check my updated answer

Comment: I got error ```SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from ((select *, count(*) as total from `product` where `content_related_group` is not null group by `content_related_group`) union (select * from `product` where `content_related_group` is null) order by `created_at` desc) as `temp_table`)```

Comment: Can post and some dummy data and provide what's the results you are expecting @Catto

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai I've provided it in my post, example is the data from database. And result is what I want